# Another "Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was BEGIN_ARRAY" question

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit2

I'm trying to change this project code (https://github.com/rygelouv/networkcall-sample) to fetch data from another URL, but I'm not able to fix "Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was BEGIN_ARRAY" error on response. 
Json response is like 
`[{"value":"1","label":"ADMIN"},{"value":"2","label":"EMPLOYEE_1"}...]`

while original response was

```
{"count": 61700,"result: false,"items": [{"id": 3436,"node":DEwOlJlyMjY2"...},{....}]}
```

I know I have to change return type to accept Array type, but I cant figure out how/where to do it because of the DSL.
In the code below I've only changed repository class to fit my needs:

```
object Repository {
    fun getRepos() = networkCall<ReposResponse, List<Employee>> {
        client = GithubAPI.githubService.getRepos()
        var result = GithubAPI.githubService.getRepos()
    }
}

data class Employee(
        @SerializedName("label")
        val name: String,

        @SerializedName("value")
        val idEmployee: String
)

data class ReposResponse(val items: List<Employee>): BaseApiResponse<Employee>(), DataResponse<List<Employee>> {
    override fun retrieveData(): List<Employee> = items
}

abstract class BaseApiResponse<T> {
    var total_count: Int = 0
    var incomplete_results: Boolean = false
}

object GithubAPI {
    var API_BASE_URL: String = "my_url"
    var httpClient = OkHttpClient.Builder()
    var builder: Retrofit.Builder = Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(API_BASE_URL)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .addCallAdapterFactory(CoroutineCallAdapterFactory())
    var retrofit = builder
            .client(httpClient.build())
            .build()

    var githubService = retrofit.create<GithubService>(GithubService::class.java)


    interface GithubService {
        @GET("workstation")
        fun getRepos(): Deferred<Response<ReposResponse>>
    }
```

What changes I've to make to make it works whit my data class?

Comment: show your current json response.

Comment: Please, post also the service class where you're defining the endpoint.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. json response is:                         [{"value":"1","label":"ADMIN"},{"value":"38","label":"NAME1"},{"value":"39","label":"NAME2"},{"value":"40","label":"NAME3"},{"value":"41","label":"NAME4"},{"value":"42","label":"NAME5"},{"value":"44","label":"NAME6"}]. Fake names, just a couple of items, but that's all

Comment: @MichaelCarpino Solved this yet?

Comment: Unfortunately no, I'm working on it. Changing the callback param create an error on the 3rd line "client = GithubAPI.githubService.getRepos()" .
 Type mismatch.Required: Deferred<Response<ReposResponse>>
Found: Deferred<Response<List<Employee>>>.  
Variable "client" it's declared in the "NetworkCallDSL" class so i'm trying to fix it but no luck

Answer (score 1):

> Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was BEGIN_ARRAY

[**`JsonSyntaxException`**](https://static.javadoc.io/com.google.code.gson/gson/2.6.2/com/google/gson/JsonSyntaxException.html) This exception is raised when Gson attempts to read (or write) a malformed JSON element.

You should change interface callback param. Add List type.

```
interface GithubService {
        @GET("workstation")
        fun getRepos(): Deferred<Response<List<Employee>>
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are expecting a `JSON object` in your app and the api is returning a `JSON array`. Your service should look like this:

```
    interface GithubService {
        @GET("workstation")
        fun getRepos(): Deferred<Response<List<Employee>>
    }
```

After this change, you can remove the `ReposResponse` class cause you're not using that structure anymore